# How do I uninstall the Chrome (OS) desktop enviroment?

Tags: uninstall, google-chrome, desktop-environments

So, yesterday I installed the Chrome OS desktop environment for Ubuntu (12.04). It didn't work (probably because the install was corrupted). But anyways, how can I remove it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I used the instructions here: https://github.com/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting Disturbed of The Chromium thing.

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>,
2. copy: `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove lightdm-login-chromiumos`
3. Enter your Password and wait.

Don't worry Ubuntu will not be affected or Screwed your PC

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstalled. Start Software Center, select installed software on top tab, search chromeos and then uninstall.